# Condense spark dataframe by selecting latest value and removing the nulls

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to condense the given sparse data frame for the given key into a single record by removing null values and selecting the latest value based on version. below is an illustration with sample data

Let's say there is an input data frame in the below format

| key | version | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | 1 | A1 | Null | Null |
| Key1 | 1 | Null | B1 | Null |
| Key1 | 1 | Null | Null | C1 |
| key1 | 2 | A2 | Null | Null |
| key1 | 2 | Null | Null | C2 |

should get converted to the below format

| key | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | A2 | B1 | C2 |

Not that the output data frame doesn't have version column. For column A there are two values A1, A2, we should pick values that have the latest version (2).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first` function over an ordered window:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('key').orderBy(F.desc('version')) \
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df2 = df.select('key',
    *[F.first(F.col(c), ignorenulls=True).over(w).alias(c) for c in ['A', 'B', 'C']]
).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks. But it failed with the error "[MISSING_AGGREGATION] The non-aggregating expression "A" is based on columns which are not participating in the GROUP BY clause.
Add the columns or the expression to the GROUP BY, aggregate the expression, or use "any_value(A)" if you do not care which of the values within a group is returned.;"

Comment: This should work.    df2 = df.select('key', *[F.first(F.col(c), ignorenulls=True).over(w).alias(c) for c in ['A', 'B', 'C']])